# Is there a way to combine Laravel query builder conditions?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-query-builder

Say I have 2 query builders:

```
$builderA = User::where("happiness", ">", 5);
$builderB = User::where("color", "blue");
```

Other than typing out a new builder, is there a way I can combine these 2 builders, resulting in the builder shown below?

```
$combined = User::where("happiness", ">", 5)->where("color", "blue");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For more complex cases, you can use `tap` and `mergeWheres`:

```
$where = User::where('a', 1)->where('b', '>', 2)->where('c', '<', 2)->where('d', '<>', 2);

$combined = User::where('e', 5)->tap(function (Builder $builder) use ($where) {
    $builder->mergeWheres($where->wheres, $where->getBindings());
});
```

Laravel 5.6 added several methods for working with subqueries:

- [selectSub](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_selectSub)
- [fromSub](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_fromSub)
- [createSub](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_createSub)
- [parseSub](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_parseSub)
- [whereSub](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_whereSub)

Comment: Oh! that may be a good reason to upgrade to Laravel 5.6. Thanks for letting me know

Comment: This answer is the closest to what I was looking for. It would have been cool if Laravel had something built in to completely merge an entire builder's conditions into another builder. Thanks for understanding what I was trying to ask here. :D

Comment: Happy to help. FYI, the upgrade from 5.5 to 5.6 is the easiest yet. Took about 15 minutes the last time I did it.

Comment: the functions you mentioned accept query builders, so that is exactly the answer I was looking for.

Comment: For Eloquent builder use `$where->getQuery()->wheres`. Works on 7.x.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.

```
$combinedUsers = User::where([
   ["happiness", ">", 5], 
   ["color" => "blue"]
])->get();
```

or

```
$combinedUsers = User::where([
   ["happiness", ">", 5], 
   ["color", "=", "blue"]
])->get();
```

In your case you must be use `orWhere`

```
// one request in db
$combinedUsers = User::where("happiness", ">", 5)->orWhere("color", "blue")->get();

// filter in Collection instance
$happyUsers = $combinedUsers->where("happiness", ">", 5); 
$blueUsers = $combinedUsers->where("color", "blue");
```

Alos you can use

```
$queryBulider = User::newQuery();
$queryBulider->...->get();
```

`$queryBulider` is instance of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`.

Comment: The key words in my question are "Other than typing out a new builder". The actual builders I'm working with are much more complicated (including custom searches and orders based on the user's settings) So I'm looking for something like $builderA->addConditions($builderB);

Comment: See updated answer. I think it must be helpful for you

Comment: docs [https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html)

Comment: @SkeetsO'Reilly, this answer is the correct answer for the context in your question. Other than this, you're going to need to extract the way that logic inside your controller or model (preferably, model)

Comment: Ok, so it's probably not possible the way I was hoping it would be. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: `$queryBulider->where("happiness", ">", 5); 
$queryBulider->where("color", "blue"); if('some condition') { 
$queryBulider->where("name", "like", "search")}`

Comment: In my usage case, I need to add the conditions of the original builder to the builder inside of a sub-query, and I also need the results of the original builder as well.

Comment: `$queryBulider->where("happiness", ">", 5); $queryBulider2 = clone $queryBulider; $queryBulider->where(function($query) {$query->where("color", "blue"); if('some condition') { $query->where("name", "like", "search")}});  $sql1 = $queryBulider->toSql(); $sql1 =  $queryBulider2->toSql();` `$sql1` must be `select * from users where happiness >= ? AND (color = ? .....)` and `$sql2` must be similar this `select * from users where happiness >= ?`

Comment: That's not a sub-query. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/subqueries.html  (Subqueries in Laravel are only possible when using "wherein", as far as I can tell) But anyway, I think I probably asked the wrong question. This question was part of my attempt to solve this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51297660/laravel-find-offset-of-record-in-mysql-results

Comment: Edit your question. and show finally what you want to get (sql syntax I will wrap it in eloquent model)

Comment: The query I'm ultimately trying to build can be found on the question I linked to. I think the question was different enough that it needed it's own question. Since I'm not actually sure such a subquery is even possible, this question isn't valid unless my other question has an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the query on base of any conditions or matching with any input then you can try this:

```
$combinedUsers = User::query();
if(YourCondition){
    $combinedUsers = $combinedUsers->where("happiness", ">", 5);
}
if(YourCondition){
    $combinedUsers = $combinedUsers->where("color","blue");
}
if(YourCondition){
    $combinedUsers = $combinedUsers->orderBy("color");
}
$combinedUsers = $combinedUsers->get();
```